# is FBWF (file based write filter) supported on Windows 7 (non embedded)

Tags: windows-7, windows-embedded-7

> File-Based Write Filter (FBWF) allows
>   Windows XP Embedded (XPe) to maintain
>   the appearance of read and write
>   access to write sensitive or read only
>   storage. FBWF makes read and write
>   access transparent to applications.

I've heard (for example [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/software/25763-file-based-write-filter-fbwf-win-7-embedded.html) that FBWF is working also on non embedded versions of windows 7 - but this appears like a hack.

I'd like to know if FBWF is indeed supported on regular windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it is supported on Windows XP (I'm assuming that where Windows XP supports this sort of feature that Windows 7 should too), although documentation is scarce (so someone wrote their own guide for using it):

Guide to using FBWF on Windows XP Pro
  http://www.mp3car.com/winnt-based/121088-guide-to-using-fbwf-on-windows-xp-pro.html

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**  Since this effects the file system, make sure you have full backups of all your important data before you begin, especially because it's [apparently] not well-documented.

Comment: This look like an "unofficial" method. do you know if it's legal?

Comment: @Ophir Yoktan: Well, a lack of documentation will cause people to figure out how to do things on their own with an in-demand technology, so I don't see any problem with labeling that information as "unofficial."  As far as the law is concerned, I'm not a lawyer but I doubt there's anything in the law books about FBWF technology that would make it legal or illegal.